# Django GetStream and Django comment

Tags: django, django-models, getstream-io

how can I save an activity from Django GetStream using django_comments and how can I get this data? Thank you!

I've implemented the Django comment with render_comment_form, something like that https://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.X/ref/contrib/comments/ and I wanna know how I can save the activity in GetStream and how can I make for consult after save thanks
Thank you man, but I have something like that:

```
from django.db import models
from fluent_comments.compat import CommentManager, Comment #, signals
from fluent_comments.models import FluentComment
from stream_django.activity import Activity
from stream_django import feed_manager
from django.db.models import signals
from publications.models import Ad

class ActivityComments(FluentComment, Activity):
    pass

    def __unicode__(self):
        #return "%s COMENTA-->> %s" % (self.user.first_name, self.object_content.item)
        return "%s COMENTA-->> %s" % (self.user.first_name, self.object_pk)

    @property
    def activity_object_attr(self):
        return self

    @property
    def activity_actor_attr(self):
        return self.user

    @property
    def activity_time(self):
        return self.created

    @property
    def extra_activity_data(self):
        return {'a': self.item}

    @property
    def activity_notify(self):
        if self.object_content.item.seller.user != self.user:
            target_feed = feed_manager.get_notification_feed(
                self.object_content.item.seller.user.id)
            return [target_feed]

    @classmethod
    def apply_activity_notify(cls, sender, instance, using, **kwargs):

        ad=Ad.objects.get(id=instance.object_pk)
        comment = FluentComment.objects.get(id=instance.id)
        comment.object_content = ad
        comment.activity_notify


"""
signals
"""

signals.post_save.connect(ActivityComments.apply_activity_notify, sender=Comment)
```

I thougth with this I can register the activiy, but when I go to the getstram administrator I can whatch nothing. Also, another question, when the register is alredy made, Can I get the activity with that?:

```
enricher = Enrich()
feed = feed_manager.get_feed('flat', user.id)
activities = feed.get(limit=3)['results']
I hope your answer, Thanks.
```

Comment: Hi! thank you but I cant look the activity in the admin, check my answers below please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django Comment allows you to customize the model used to store comments.

First you need to create an application to hold Django Comment's customization and add this to your settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'my_comment_app',
]

COMMENTS_APP = 'my_comment_app'
```

then in my_comment_app/models.py you need register your Comment model as Stream activity.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment
from stream_django.activity import Activity

class ActivityComment(Comment, Activity):
    pass
```

then you need to register your custom application to Django Comment, to do this add to my_comment_app/__init__.py this code

```
from my_comment_app.models import ActivityComment


def get_model():
    return ActivityComment
```

Comment: Hey man! you know how add the activites to the tabs notifications? this activites are another of the folow, I'll appreciate your answers.

Comment: @PabloAlejandro I think the best is if you create a new question with the same tag, feel free to ping me there ;)